# Python_Creating empty lists and naming by iterators

Tags: python, list

I'd like to create a bunch of empty lists and name them thru iterations, but the code keeps error out showing "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator".
My purpose is to create lists named 5R05D, 15R05D, 15R20D etc..
Appreciate for any help!

```
MA = ['5','15','30','60']
For each in MA:
    each+'R05D'=[]
    each+'R10D'=[]
    each+'R20D'=[]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? why not use a dict instead?

Comment: TL:DR don't do this. Use a container, like a list or a dict

Answer (score 2):

You can't create variables like that. For one thing, Python variable names can not start with a digit. You would be better off with a dictionary using `'5R05D'` (and similar) as a key, and lists as the values:

```
MA = ['5','15','30','60']
d = {}
for each in MA:
    d[each+'R05D'] = []
    d[each+'R10D'] = []
    d[each+'R20D'] = []

>>> d
{'5R05D': [], '5R10D': [], '5R20D': [], '15R05D': [], '15R10D': [], '15R20D': [], '30R05D': [], '30R10D': [], '30R20D': [], '60R05D': [], '60R10D': [], '60R20D': []}
```